# How to make Constraints programmatically in iOS Swift 3.1?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, margin

Hello i want to make constraint like this images in swift code:

**A- Margin from left and right and bottom:**

[image]

**B- Horizontal center:**

[image]

**C- last figure:**

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Comment: This is not duplicate and i think it's better to try answer the question BRO @Rishabh :|

Comment: @reza_khalafi look into http://janeshsuthar.blogspot.in/2017/07/ios-uiviewconstraints.html.